# Real world stat practice

Tags: self-study, references

I've been taking courses in Applied Statistics and through the homework problems I get to practice what I've learned.  But, I find that the practice problems are always a bit contrived to fit within the context of the chapter and often not reflective or real life problems.

In an effort to get more practice and especially in real world situations, I would like to find examples that I can consider how to approach.  Of course, it would be nice if there was an actual approach that was taken, to help gauge my understanding.

Cross Validated is extremely helpful, but the questions aren't really geared toward practice of the technique, or discovering the right technique for the problem.  Kaggle is also great, but those are usually much more complicated.

Any other ideas where I might find such practice sets with actual solutions?

EDIT:  Trying to add a bit more color...

As I've taken classes, I find myself doing very well on homework and exams, which is great, but what is lacking is a real world perspective.  Obviously the problems on homework and exams are specifically geared toward the particular techniques we have just studied, so I feel that I lack that organic problem solving ability that can likely only come through experience.

Ideally, I would like to find examples of real world statistical problems along with the approaches that people have taken to those problems.  Something akin to the problems in the chapters of a statistics textbook, but real problems with the real approaches that were taken.  The intent would be to gain a better understanding of the types of problems statisticians/machine learning engineers are faced with and how they approach those problems.

Comment: I could not come up with a good tag for this one.  I tried "statistical-learning" but it was changed to "machine-learning"

Comment: "Statistical learning"  is used pretty much analogously to "machine learning" -- e.g. see https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/ or https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ ... `self-study` might work but it's application is more specific (here it's used to indicate your question relates to coursework / bookwork and tells answerers something of the style of answer needed -- to offer hints and guidance). If you're seeking books with analysis of real data sets, try the `references` tag.

Comment: While requests for specific data sets are off topic (try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), your question is a little broader (so I haven't closed it). One resource that might be of some value to you -- the DASL (Data and Story Library) repository which used to be maintained at cmu (it was at lib.stat.cmu.edu/DASL/)  -- but the [internet archive of it](https://web.archive.org/web/*/lib.stat.cmu.edu/DASL/) seems to be incomplete (you can try https://dasl.datadescription.com/datafiles/ but it's not quite what it was; nevertheless it may be close to what you seek)

Comment: Thanks for the tag suggestion, the resource, and keeping the question open.

Comment: It may still end up closed, though. NB I have made a few minor edits to my earlier comment, to help out other people trying to find out about DASL

Comment: I looked at the references you cited, and both look interesting.  I'm also interested in finding out how others approach the problem.  Trying my own approaches is helpful but knowing how others approached the analysis would help broaden my view.

Comment: The two links (not counting the one to opendata) should just be different versions of the same DASL repository; I haven't had time to check out the new one yet, but it hopefully at least has all the same sets of data and descriptions. You may want to expand further on what you're seeking in your question.